# "apexClass" is invalid. Provide the API name of an Apex class that includes an Apex data type supported in flows

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, unmanaged-package, package-install, invocablevariable

We have created a unmanaged package to migrate to a new org. It builds the package successfully and it runs fine in the old org but when we go to install in the new org we get the following error:

```
(Accrue_CreateLoanWithAutomationV2-9) CDLinkCollection (Variable) - "apexClass" is invalid. Provide the API name of an Apex class that includes an Apex data type supported in flows.
Accrue_CreateLoanWithAutomationV2-9: CDLinkCollection (Variable) - "apexClass" is invalid. Provide the API name of an Apex class that includes an Apex data type supported in flows.
```

The apex class is included in the package. Below is the apex class throwing the error:

```java
public class ContentDocumentLinkInput {
    @InvocableVariable
    @AuraEnabled public String targetRecordId;
    @InvocableVariable
    @AuraEnabled public String contentDocumentLinkId;
}
```

We have also tried converting this to a global class but it still fails.

Comment: Do you have any dependencies - a different unmanaged package or managed package or app exchange app or anything of the sort - that your code directly or indirectly relies upon, that might not be in the new org?

Comment: We have the same managed packages installed in the new org and all unmanaged packages are in our unmanaged package

Comment: Does your package include permissions for the Apex class?  https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2020/critical-update-ensure-users-have-access-to-auraenabled-methods

Comment: Yes it does include all permissions.

Comment: Is there a flow included with the package? This error feels like it's there, and not in apex

Comment: Yes, it does include a flow but the issue lies in that flow apex object. The flow runs fine in the old org but won’t install in the new org.